# Google or Amazon-like autocomplete keywords suggestion in Algolia

Tags: autocomplete, keyword, algolia

How do I achieve a keyword based autocomplete suggestions in Algolia similar to something like Amazon or Google?

I attempted building the autocomplete based on multiple attributes of an Algolia document, however its purpose does not really help me at completing a phrase but it directs me at selecting a specific product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I attempted building the autocomplete based on multiple attributes of an Algolia document, however its purpose does not really help me at completing a phrase but it directs me at selecting a specific product.

If you want to suggest some searches instead of products/objects you can build an index with your searches logs. You can use Algolia's Analytics API + [top searches](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/analytics/#get-top-searches) endpoint to get them if you don't have them yet.

You could then store them in a `popular_searches` index like that:

```
{
  "value": "my popular search",
  "count": 42 // the search frequency
}
```

And configure:

- `searchableAttribute` to target the `value` attribute
- `customRanking` to use `desc(count)` as the attribute reflecting the popularity

That being said, **you should know that such popular searches autocomplete can be super complex to setup** to reach the UX of Amazon/Google:

- make sure that the searches you use are popular enough (remove low frequencies)
- make sure the searches you use are actually retrieving results -> to ensure your users will get results while selecting it from the dropdown menu (you can query your product index at build-time)
- make sure your searches are not containing SPAM (super easy to do a script bombarding your API to make a spam search very popular so it goes in your dropdown menu)
- make sure your searches don't include offensive/bad words :) (Even google has a hard time with that)

**tldr;** If you have choice, precompute a list of searches from your products/objects instead of using your query logs :) It will be safer & easier to maintain (I'm pretty sure that's what Amazon do).

Comment: Thank you, awesome response.

Answer (score -2):

I have not used algolia but google returns https://www.algolia.com/doc/search/auto-complete#introduction

Comment: It does not really help me. I tried it but it does directs me to specific products instead of an efficient search phrase.